# Milnor's proof of the fundamental theorem of algebra (Topology from the Differentiable Viewpoint)

Tags: polynomials, manifolds, differential-topology

I am studying the proof of the fundamental theorem of algebra out of John Milnor's book *Topology from the Differentiable Viewpoint*, located on page 8 here:

http://webmath2.unito.it/paginepersonali/sergio.console/Dispense/Milnor%20Topology%20from%20%23681EA.pdf.

My questions concern the last line of the proof. I cannot understand why $f$ being zero nowhere implies that it is an onto function - is it because it is an injective map from two finite sets? And why does $f$ being a bijection imply that the polynomial $P$ has a zero? I can see that $f$ is a composition of functions including $P$, but there seems to be a leap here that I am missing.

Comment: where is that PDF?

Comment: Added now, sorry!

Comment: Since $\#f^{-1}(y) > 0$ for all $y$, the function $f$ is onto.

Answer (score 6):

He has proven that the function $$y\to\sharp f^{-1}(y)$$ is constant on the set of regular values. Assume now that $f$ is not surjective, i.e. there is some $y_0$ with $$\sharp f^{-1}(y_0)=0.$$
This $y_0$ is then a regular value. (To check this look at the definition of "regular value".) Thus
$$\sharp f^{-1}(y)=0$$
for all regular values $y$, so every point is a critical value of $f$. But this is of course not possible: a polynomial of degree $d$ has at most $d-1$ critical points, hence at most $d-1$ critical values, so not all points can be critical values of $f$.